# Como selecionar o atributo logUser apenas no objeto principal do JSON usando Regex

Tags: json, regex

Preciso selecionar o atributo **logUser** apenas no Objeto principal do JSON caso o mesmo venha com valor ou null.

**Ex:** ***logUser: 100 | logUser: null***

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "numeracao": "001",
    "logUser": 100,
    "permissionario": {
        "id": 3113715,
        "nome": "ARTHUR MATHEUS SÉRGIO DA SILVA",
        "dataDeNascimento": "2000-12-10",
        "endLogradouro": "RUA TERESINA",
        "endNumero": "89465468",
        "endBairro": "ROSA DOS VENTOS",
        "endCidade": "PARNAMIRIM",
        "endUf": "RN",
        "endCep": "59142125",
        "endComplemento": null,
        "telefoneFixo": null,
        "telefoneMovel": "(94) 949849849",
        "email": null,
        "logDate": "2019-01-16",
        "logUser": null,
        "sexo": "MASCULINO",
        "foto": null,
        "cpf": "10322314593",
        "estadoCivil": "CASADO",
        "cnhNumero": null,
        "cnhCategoria": null,
        "cnhValidade": null,
        "rgNumero": "64684654",
        "rgOrgaoExpeditor": "SSP",
        "rgDataEmissao": null,
        "rgUF": "RN",
        "status": true
    },
    "veiculo": {    
        "id": 3,
        "placa": "JUQ9196",
        "marca": "RENAULT",
        "modelo": "SC",
        "renavam": "54840252144",
        "anoDeFabricacao": "2006",
        "corPredominante": "BRANCO",
        "logCidadao": null,
        "status": true,
        "logUser": null,
        "logDate": "2019-01-16T11:05:10.425",
        "version": 1
    },
    "logDate": "2019-01-16T11:05:13.264",
    "status": true,
    "version": 0,
    "motorista": {
        "id": 3113717,
        "nome": "DAVI LEVI GALVÃO",
        "dataDeNascimento": "1996-10-20",
        "endLogradouro": "RUA FRANCISCO FERREIRA DA SILVA",
        "endNumero": "911",
        "endBairro": "VALE DO SOL",
        "endCidade": "PARNAMIRIM",
        "endUf": "RN",
        "endCep": "59143025",
        "endComplemento": null,
        "telefoneFixo": "8429884472",
        "telefoneMovel": "84995302167",
        "email": "ddavilevigalvao@mtic.net.br",
        "logDate": "2019-01-16",
        "logUser": null,
        "sexo": "MASCULINO",
        "foto": null,
        "cpf": "98842966428",
        "estadoCivil": "CASADO",
        "cnhNumero": null,
        "cnhCategoria": null,
        "cnhValidade": null,
        "rgNumero": "184962122",
        "rgOrgaoExpeditor": "SSP",
        "rgDataEmissao": null,
        "rgUF": "RN",
        "status": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Precisa necessariamente ser com regex?

Comment: A maioria das linguagens (se não todas) possuem libs prontas para ler e manipular JSON, então use a ferramenta adequada para cada tarefa. Inclusive manipular o objeto JSON com a lib adequada será muito mais fácil que usar uma regex, e menos propenso a erros também - por exemplo, uma regex não verifica se o JSON está bem formado, se há erros de sintaxe, etc (e verificar isso com regex [é tão complicado que não vale a pena](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2583472)). Regex é legal, mas [nem sempre é a melhor solução](https://bit.ly/2aarqwx)

Comment: Não necessariamente precisa ser regex. Acho que expresseiu mal a questão. Esse JSON e interceptado em um filtro no meio da requisição, eu trato o mesmo como uma String para poder adicionar o atributo **logUser** caso o mesmo não venha contido no Objeto ou altera-lo caso venha. Optei por regex para evitar de ficar percorrendo a string em busca do atributo, porem me deparei com esse problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Não use regex para isso

Você pode até achar que regex é uma boa ideia para este caso, mas acredite, não é.

Provavelmente você pensou que seria algo simples como `"logUser"\s*\:([^\,]+),` (a palavra `logUser` entre aspas, seguido ou não de espaços, seguido de `:`, seguido de vários caracteres que não são vírgula, seguido de vírgula). [E aparentemente "funciona"](https://regex101.com/r/cnYhrJ/2).

O problema é que esta regex não valida se toda a string de fato é um JSON, o que já é uma grande desvantagem. Você não quer apenas verificar se existe uma linha cujos caracteres estejam em um determinado formato. Você quer verificar se os dados são de fato um JSON válido (que é um tipo específico de dados, [com formato e tipos bem definidos](https://www.json.org/)), e se este JSON possui determinada chave. E isso a regex não faz.

É até possível validar um JSON usando regex, mas sinceramente, [é tão complicado](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2583472) que na minha opinião não vale a pena (talvez **apenas** como curiosidade e/ou para se aprofundar na sintaxe de regex).

Além disso, a regex que sugeri é ingênua demais. Primeiro que ela aceita JSONs inválidos como:

```
{ "logUser":::::::123, "etc" ... }
{ "logUser":  , }
```

Isso por causa do `[^,]`, que significa *"qualquer caractere que não seja vírgula"*, ou seja, se tiver vários espaços ou vários `:`, a regex considera válido. Podemos criar expressões mais complicadas (como a do [link já citado](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2583472)), que validam corretamente strings, números, etc, mas mesmo assim ainda há outros problemas.

Por exemplo, você só quer o "logUser" do primeiro nível. Mas a regex não consegue verificar em qual nível a chave está:

```
{
    "abc": 123,
    "logUser": 123, <-- deveria pegar só esse
    "segundoNivel": {
        "logUser": 123, <-- não deveria pegar esse, pois não está no primeiro nível (mas pega)
    },
    ...
}
```

Claro, eu poderia fazer com que a regex só pegue a primeira ocorrência de "logUser", mas o JSON também poderia estar assim:

```
{
    "abc": 123,
    "segundoNivel": {
        "logUser": 123, <-- não deveria pegar esse, pois não está no primeiro nível (mas pega)
    },
    "logUser": 123, <-- deveria pegar só esse
    ...
}
```

Lembre-se que um objeto JSON é um [*unordered set*](https://www.json.org/) (conjunto **não-ordenado**) de pares chave/valor, o que significa que a ordem das chaves não é garantida, e dependendo da biblioteca/linguagem utilizada, pode ser que o "logUser" apareça da maneira acima. E a regex não vai te salvar nestes casos (a menos que você se aventure com [regex recursivas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3845829), que além de complicado, nem todas as linguagens suportam).

Claro que você poderia verificar se a linha começa com 4 espaços (uma forma de "garantir" que está no primeiro nível), mas aí você teria que garantir que o JSON sempre estará formatado desta maneira (e essa garantia tem que ser feita fora da regex). Mas já que você vai formatar o JSON - de preferência usando alguma biblioteca - por que já não aproveita e usa esta biblioteca para validá-lo e verificar/obter o campo que precisa?

Enfim, [neste link](https://regex101.com/r/cnYhrJ/3) você pode ver a regex "funcionando" para estes casos. Evidentemente dá para melhorá-la, trocando a vírgula por `[,}]` ("vírgula ou `}`", pois "logUser" pode ser o último elemento, aí não vai ter vírgula, e sim `}`), ou colocando algo como `"\w+"|\d+` (caracteres entre aspas **ou** números) para restringir mais os valores, etc. Mas no fim você vai acabar com expressões gigantescas como as [deste link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2583472), o que na minha opinião faz com que não valha a pena usar regex.

---

### Use a ferramenta certa

Regex é uma ferramenta poderosa e muito legal, mas [nem sempre é a melhor solução](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Se seus dados são um objeto JSON, use uma biblioteca dedicada. Você não especificou qual linguagem está usando, mas a grande maioria delas (se não todas) possui alguma biblioteca para manipular/ler/validar/converter JSON.

Aí bastaria ler os dados e verificar se existe a chave "logUser" no primeiro nível (e obter seu valor facilmente para compará-lo com o que você quiser, etc), sem precisar se preocupar com todos os problemas citados anteriormente, e sem precisar construir uma regex super-complicada (não só de fazer, mas de manter futuramente também).

Usar a ferramenta errada só vai - desnecessariamente - te trazer problemas que você não teria se usasse a ferramenta correta.

[image]

---

Apenas alguns exemplos para você ver como é muito mais simples não usar regex. Como você não especificou qual linguagem está usando, escolhi algumas "aleatoriamente". O JSON foi simplificado para não deixar o código muito longo, mas todos funcionam para o seu JSON também.

Em Python, basta usar o [módulo `json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html):

```py
import json

def test(texto):
    # transforma o texto em um objeto JSON
    json_obj = json.loads(texto)
    # verifica se possui logUser no primeiro nível
    if 'logUser' in json_obj:
        print('logUser está no primeiro nível, valor=', json_obj['logUser'])
    else:
        print('logUser não está no primeiro nível')

# logUser no primeiro nível
test("""
    {
      "abc": "cde",
      "logUser": "xyz",
      "segundoNivel": {
        "etc": 123
      }
    }""");

# logUser no segundo nível
test("""
    {
      "abc": "cde",
      "segundoNivel": {
        "logUser": "xyz",
        "etc": 123
      }
    }""")
```

Em Java, há várias bibliotecas disponíveis, como o [pacote `org.json`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20180813), o [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) do Google, etc. Todas funcionam de maneira bem parecida (recebem uma string e convertem para um objeto JSON, que pode ser usado para verificar se a chave existe e obter seu valor). Um exemplo com `org.json.JSONObject`:

```java
public void verifica(String texto) {
    // transforma a string em um objeto JSON
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(texto);
    // verifica se possui logUser no primeiro nível
    if (obj.has("logUser")) {
        System.out.println("possui logUser no primeiro nível, valor=" + obj.getString("logUser"));
    } else {
        System.out.println("não possui logUser no primeiro nível");
    }
}

// possui logUser no primeiro nível
verifica("{ \"abc\": \"cde\", \"logUser\": \"xyz\", \"segundoNivel\": { \"etc\": 123 } }");
// não possui logUser no primeiro nível
verifica("{ \"abc\": \"cde\", \"segundoNivel\": { \"logUser\": \"xyz\", \"etc\": 123 } }");
```

Em PHP, você pode usar [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode):

```php
function verifica($texto) {
    // converte o texto para objeto JSON
    $json = json_decode($texto);
    // verifica se logUser está no primeiro nível
    if (array_key_exists('logUser', $json)) {
        echo "\nlogUser está no primeiro nível, valor=". $json->logUser;
    } else{
        echo "\nlogUser não está no primeiro nível";
    }
}

// logUser no primeiro nível
verifica('{ "abc": "cde", "logUser": "xyz", "segundoNivel": { "etc": 123 } }');

// logUser no segundo nível
verifica('{ "abc": "cde", "segundoNivel": { "logUser": "xyz", "etc": 123 } }');
```

Como você disse que quer verificar se `logUser` existe, mesmo que o valor seja nulo, eu usei [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php), que verifica se a chave existe, independente do valor. Se quiser descartar valores nulos, [pode trocar por `isset`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10176383).

Por fim, em JavaScript, use o [objeto `JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON):

```js
function verifica(elemento){
  // pega o texto do elemento
  let texto = document.querySelector(elemento).value;

  // transforma o texto em um objeto JSON
  let json = JSON.parse(texto);

  // verifica se possui logUser no primeiro nível
  if (json.logUser) {
    console.log(`${elemento} possui logUser no primeiro nível, valor=${json.logUser}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`${elemento} não possui logUser no primeiro nível`);
  }
}

verifica('#logUserPrimeiroNivel');
verifica('#logUserSegundoNivel');
```

```html
<textarea id="logUserPrimeiroNivel" rows="8">
{
  "abc": "cde",
  "logUser": "xyz",
  "segundoNivel": {
    "etc": 123
  }
}
</textarea>

<textarea id="logUserSegundoNivel" rows="8">
{
  "abc": "cde",
  "segundoNivel": {
    "logUser": "xyz",
    "etc": 123
  }
}
</textarea>
```

Enfim, a maioria das linguagens possui alguma biblioteca para lidar com JSON, e todas costumam funcionar de maneira similar (transforme a string em objeto JSON, verifique se a chave existe, pegue seu valor). E repare nos exemplos acima que o código é bem simples, muito mais fácil de entender e manter do que [isso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3845829):

```php
$pcre_regex = '
  /
  (?(DEFINE)
     (?<number>   -? (?= [1-9]|0(?!\d) ) \d+ (\.\d+)? ([eE] [+-]? \d+)? )    
     (?<boolean>   true | false | null )
     (?<string>    " ([^"\\\\]* | \\\\ ["\\\\bfnrt\/] | \\\\ u [0-9a-f]{4} )* " )
     (?<array>     \[  (?:  (?&json)  (?: , (?&json)  )*  )?  \s* \] )
     (?<pair>      \s* (?&string) \s* : (?&json)  )
     (?<object>    \{  (?:  (?&pair)  (?: , (?&pair)  )*  )?  \s* \} )
     (?<json>   \s* (?: (?&number) | (?&boolean) | (?&string) | (?&array) | (?&object) ) \s* )
  )
  \A (?&json) \Z
  /six   
';
```

E isso é somente para verificar se a string é um JSON válido. Você ainda precisa modificá-la para encaixar a verificação de `logUser` apenas no primeiro nível. Lembrando que a regex acima faz uso de recursão, que [não é suportado por todas as linguagens](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html#engines).

Definitivamente, regex **não** é a melhor opção para o seu caso.

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela otima explicação. Realmente o Regex não foi a melhor saida. Consegui resolver com uma lib da linguagem(JAVA) que estava usando.

Answer (score 1):

> "*- Preciso selecionar o atributo logUser apenas no Objeto principal do JSON*"

É possível, mas não recomendado!

> **@off-topic:** Existem bibliotecas de *JSON* para quase todas (se não todas) as principais linguagens de programação. É muito melhor, e mais seguro, retornar o valor de tal propriedade direto com o *JSON*.

Não vou estender muito sobre, já que a [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/357086/45810) do [@hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) já explica precisamente as vantagens de utilizar uma biblioteca JSON e as desvantagens de utilizar expressão regular.

Mas, se ainda assim, você quiser utilizar expressão regular, pode fazer assim:

```
/\"logUser\"(?=.*\:)([\s\:]+)([^\,}]+?)(\,|\})/
```

Explicando:

1. Busca `"logUser"`;
2. Busca espaço (`\s`) e dois pontos (`:`) **uma ou mais vezes**, e o *[positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)* força a ter dois pontos (`:`);
3. Busca **qualquer coisa diferente de vírgula (`,`) ou fecha-chave (`}`)**, que é o valor que você precisa;
4. Busca o delimitador do valor, que pode ser uma vírgula (`,`) ou fecha-chave (`}`);

Veja este [exemplo funcional](https://regex101.com/r/NCG96s/1).

Note que não utilizei o modificador **global**, já que você quer apenas o objeto principal. O valor que você precisa é capturado no segundo grupo: `$2`.

Agora basta você capturar o "*match*" no seu projeto. Não vou exemplificar, já que você não mencionou qual a linguagem está usando, etc...

## Devo reiterar que a melhor solução é utilizar uma biblioteca JSON!

Mas se quer mesmo utilizar a expressão regular, certifique-se de que esse JSON sempre será válido e seguirá tal estrutura.

Se sempre estiver com esse padrão de [indentação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o), pode adicionar uma busca de 4 espaços (`\s`) no início da linha para certificar-se que seja mesmo no "primeiro nível" do JSON. [Veja neste link](https://regex101.com/r/NCG96s/2).

> Sou pato em expressão regular. Formulei esta resposta a fim de exercitar e "demonstrar possibilidades". Considere seguir as recomendações da [mencionada resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/357086/45810), ao invés de "reinventar a roda"...

Agradecimentos especiais pelas colocações do [@hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo).

Comment: Usar `[\s\:]+` faz com que aceite somente espaços (e nenhum `:`) entre a chave e o valor, o que é inválido em JSON. Há outros problemas também, veja [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/p8JiXD/3) - na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/357086/112052) usei uma regex parecida, mas no fim concluí que ela tem mais problemas do que vantagens. E fazer uma regex mais precisa é tão complicado que não vale a pena. O melhor mesmo é não usar regex, e sim uma lib de JSON :-)

Comment: Justo. Como mencionei no off-topic, a lib é literalmente a melhor opção... Logo, se lembrar, implemento essa expressão seguindo sua colocação. Não faço agora pq não estou perto do PC. E celular não rola! Kkkk

Comment: @hkotsubo não tinha muito oque fazer. Sua resposta já abordou quase tudo. Mas ainda assim, reformulei corrigindo algumas coisas e enfatizando a questão da biblioteca... No mais, obrigado!