# como traduzir um JSON

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

Tenho um JSON aqui com 1000 objetos dentro de uma array, ta em inglês, o problema e que quero traduzir para pt-Br e quando uso o google tradutor simplesmente buga, por ex

> { "description": "Do you like donuts? If you're also a donuts lover,
>   come on and enjoy it!"}, { "description": "(segundo ex aleatorio em
>   inglês...)" } ... + 1000

em algumas linhas as descrições permanece em inglês em outras não mesmo passando pelo google tradutor, tem outro jeito de traduzir? Pois preciso das descrições em pt-Br, para puxar os dados dentro de uma lista em loop listando todas as descrições, então preciso que o nome do item description permaneca para dar item.description e listar todas, tem outro jeito mais funcional?

uso vuejs

Comment: Nesse caso, você vai precisar de um tradutor que aceite o formato JSON. Seja online, ou API, como por exemplo o [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/docs-api.html). Lembrando que [é pago](https://www.deepl.com/pro.html#developer). Apesar de ser barato, você paga um adicional conforme a quantidade de caracteres traduzidos. Ou quem sabe a [API Translation da Google](https://cloud.google.com/translate/?hl=pt-br) que pode sair bem mais barato. 

Comment: É um array com description apenas? Pode usar um regex para extrair só as frases para um arquivo de texto, traduzir, depois outro regex para montar de novo o JSON. Isso assumindo que o problema da tradução é pelo formato, não pelas frases.

Comment: e uma unica array com 1000 objetos dentro, cada um tem uma descrição, to vendo aqui regex parece que resolve mas eu tenho que colocar 500 objetos por vez pq senão pesa demais e cai o regex, to vendo aqui consigo selecionar no regex { "description":"counteudo"} colocando = (?:"description":")(.*?)(?:") mas eu quero so selecionar o conteúdo sem aspas como faco ?

Comment: Se vc está usando JavaScript e recebe um JSON, [não precisa usar regex](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/357086/112052). O próprio JavaScript possui o método `JSON.parse` que transforma a string contendo o JSON em arrays e objetos da própria linguagem, [que tornam muito mais fácil manipular esses dados](https://hkotsubo.github.io/blog/2019-04-13/como-ler-e-manipular-um-json#javascript) (basta um for no array de objetos, acessando o description de cada um). E tb tem o método `JSON.stringify` que transforma de volta para uma string contendo todo o JSON. Usar regex é complicar à toa...

Comment: Mas se quer mesmo usar regex - que novamente, não recomendo, use o JavaScript e seja feliz :-) - pode usar algo como `"description"\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"`, que pode funcionar para a maioria dos casos ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/wQVAtG/2/)). O problema é que pode ter aspas escapadas na string (`\"`), aí a regex [fica bem mais complicada](https://regex101.com/r/RFmUCf/1/). Novamente, não vale a pena usar regex, ainda mais quando o JavaScript já possui nativamente ferramentas mais adequadas para lidar com JSON :-)

Comment: Eu tentei fazer assim, dei um v-for numa li acessando a description de cada item, assim <li v-for="item in json"> {{ item.description }} </li> (retorna as 1000 descrições cruas em texto), concatenando com html [{"description":"{{ item.description }}"}] criando uma array de objtos de descrição direto no browser problema e que qnd faco isso o google tradutor ele cria aspas nas descrições bugando o json, vou tentar aprender a traduzir e passa pelo JSON.stringify

Comment: https://www.logisticinfotech.com/translate-language-files-online-json/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido usando
https://www.logisticinfotech.com/translate-language-files-online-json/

Tbm tem outro jeito que e extrair com regex e juntar as partes como o amigo acima disse mas e mais mt mais trabalhoso visto que o json tem objetos com vários items, da pra juntar com json decode/encode e array merge, a tradução acima chega ao nível google tradutor e respeita a formação json, a estrutura fica intacta e valida diferente do google.