# Tratamento de dados em formato JSON com RegEx em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, regex

Estou com um problema em um projeto com Backend em PHP e front em HTML, JavaScript e CSS.

O backend está mandando os dados para o front através de JSON, porém, em um dos trechos dos dados há textos com aspas, exemplo:

```js
{
   "descrição": "Eu faço trabalhos "fáceis" porém cansativos"
}
```

O JSON por padrão reconhece as aspas de `"fáceis"` como final do dado, e gostaria que não fosse assim.

Posso dar um:

```js
myJson.replace(/"/g,'&quot;');
```

Mas aí ele irá trocar todas as aspas do JSON, gerando um input assim:

```js
{
   &quot;descrição&quot;: &quot;Eu faço trabalhos &quot;fáceis&quot; porém cansativos&quot;
}
```

O que quebra tudo.

Estou buscando escrever uma regex que substitui as aspas por `&quot;` apenas no caso de estarem dentro de um campo de dados do JSON. Ou há alguma outra forma de tratar este caso?

Comment: Se o JSON está com as aspas exatamente assim, então o erro está no backend, que está gerando um JSON inválido, e é lá que deveria ser corrigido. Tentar arrumar com regex não é simples ([não use regex para manipular JSON](https://hkotsubo.github.io/blog/2019-04-13/como-ler-e-manipular-um-json#regex) - para um válido [já é difícil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/357086/112052), para um inválido, é pior ainda). Provavelmente vc vai ter que manipular a string manualmente mesmo, já que geralmente os parsers dão erro qdo o JSON está inválido (ou corrija onde ele é gerado, que é o mais indicado)

Comment: Saulo, seria interessante você adicionar na pergunta o código que gera o JSON, ou pelo menos informar qual linguagem você está usando para gerar este JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como eu já disse [nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/402527/tratamento-de-dados-em-formato-json-com-regex-em-javascript#comment789534_402527), se o JSON está vindo com as aspas exatamente dessa maneira, então ele não é um JSON válido. Nesse caso, o melhor é corrigir no backend, para que ele gere o JSON corretamente - no caso, com as aspas escapadas (`\"`):

```js
{
    "descrição": "Eu faço trabalhos \"fáceis\" porém cansativos"
}
```

Tratar o problema na origem garante que quem for receber esses dados não precisará se preocupar em arrumá-los, até porque não é uma tarefa tão simples assim.

Como você disse que o backend é PHP, verifique se está usando corretamente a função [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) (que é a maneira mais simples para gerar JSON no PHP). Ou, caso esteja usando outro mecanismo/API/framework, verifique se tudo está corretamente configurado, se os parâmetros estão corretos, etc, pois é mais provável que o problema esteja aí.

O restante da resposta abaixo é somente para mostrar como usar regex pode ser uma solução ruim, mais complicada e até desnecessária, caso você corrija o problema na origem.

---

Veja por exemplo como ficaria uma regex para o seu caso (*não vai funcionar em todos os browsers*):

```js
let s = `{
   "descrição": "Eu faço trabalhos "fáceis" porém cansativos",
   "teste": "Aqui não tem aspas a mais",
   "teste2": "Aqui " tem várias " aspas a mais""
}`;
let r = /(?<!"\s*:\s*)"(?![\n\r,:]|[^"]+":)/g;
console.log(s.replace(r, '&quot;'));
```

Basicamente, ela pega as aspas, levando em consideração vários fatores:

O [*negative lookbehind*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<!"\s*:\s*)` verifica se algo **não** existe antes das aspas. No caso, temos uma aspas, seguida de `\s*` (zero ou mais espaços), dois pontos, zero ou mais espaços. Ou seja, não pode ser a primeira aspas logo depois do `:`.

***Obs**: o lookbehind atualmente [só funciona no Chrome](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/361801/112052). Mas mesmo que você use outra linguagem - que não JavaScript - que suporte este recurso, ainda sim vale ler o restante da resposta*.

O *negative lookeahead* `(?![\n\r,:]|[^"]+":)` verifica se algo **não** existe depois das aspas. No caso, é `[\n\r,:]` (uma quebra de linha, ou vírgula, ou dois pontos). Assim, eu não considero as aspas de fechamento. Mas o `|` ([que significa **ou**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)) admite outra possibilidade: `[^"]+:` - um ou mais caracteres que não sejam aspas, seguido de dois pontos (sem isso, a regex também pegava a primeira aspas de cada linha).

Basicamente, todas essas regras são para desconsiderar as aspas de abertura e fechamento legítimas. Mas esta regex não cobre todos os casos.

---

Por exemplo, se tivermos um array, não funciona mais:

```js
let s = `{
   "lista": [ "Eu faço trabalhos "fáceis" porém cansativos" ]
}`;
let r = /(?<!"\s*:\s*)"(?![\n\r,:]|[^"]+":)/g;
console.log(s.replace(r, '&quot;'));
```

Nesse caso, ele substitui todas as aspas dentro do array. Então precisamos colocar mais condições na regex para indicar a nova condição. Por exemplo, eu poderia indicar que deve ignorar as aspas logo depois do `[` ou logo antes do `]`:

```js
let s = `{
   "lista": [ "Eu faço trabalhos "fáceis" porém cansativos" ]
}`;
let r = /(?<!"\s*:\s*|[\[,]\s*)"(?![\n\r,:]|[^"]+":|\s*\])/g;
console.log(s.replace(r, '&quot;'));
```

Mas ainda há casos em que ela pode falhar. Por exemplo, se dentro da string tivermos algum desses caracteres, como `:` ou `[]`:

```js
let s = `{
   "fad": "fasdfa "fa" : "fasdfasd"sdfa",
   "xyz": [ "af [ "xyz " ad", " fasd "fasf" dfs"]
}`;
let r = /(?<!"\s*:\s*|[\[,]\s*)"(?![\n\r,:]|[^"]+":|\s*\])/g;
console.log(s.replace(r, '&quot;'));
```

Agora, como dentro das strings eu tenho os caracteres `:` e `[]` (que eu tinha usado como os pontos de referência para saber se estou no início ou fim da uma string), a regex se perde, pois ela não está verificando se deveria estar dentro de uma string ou não.

Eu até acredito que seja possível prosseguir e incluir esta alteração, mas acho que a regex já está complicada o suficiente e não vale mais a pena.

---

Tudo isso é para mostrar que talvez não valha a pena tentar corrigir o JSON com regex. Tente arrumar o JSON onde ele é gerado, em vez de [criar um problema maior ao tentar resolvê-lo com regex](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Comment: A resposta é muito boa, mas acho que a pergunta ainda não merecia uma resposta, pois do jeito que está, o AP vai usar regex pra resolver um problema que deveria ser feito no backend (mesmo você tendo advertido para não fazer isso)...

Comment: @fernandosavio Minha intenção era mostrar como a solução com regex é complicada e não vale a pena, mas o que vc falou faz sentido. Se bem que, seguir ou não a recomendação já é uma decisão do AP, pois o aviso foi dado... Mas creio que basta surgir um JSON um pouquinho mais complicado para ele perceber que de fato não vale a pena...

Comment: Exato, a resposta é boa, meu medo é que seja usada no lado negro da força. :P
Por via das dúvidas vou perguntar para o AP qual é o código que gera o JSON, pode evitar que uma boa alma use regex pra isso no futuro.

Comment: @fernandosavio É, esqueci de perguntar isso... Mas se o backend é PHP, eu acho que ele não deve estar usando `json_encode`, pois não vejo uma situação em que ele gera um JSON inválido assim... De qualquer forma, coloquei mais alguns avisos no início da resposta..

Comment: Cara, duvido que uma biblioteca nativa de qualquer linguagem de backend gere um JSON com um erro tão básico destes... Enfim, se o AP tiver interesse em uma solução para o problema real dele, só vai depender dele agora. :D Toma meu +1