# Utilizando Regex para dar match aspas após delimitador

Tags: json, regex

Preciso usar regex para dar *match* em todas as ocorrências de aspas duplas após os dois pontos (`:`) em uma saída JSON.

JSON:

```js
{
    "data":  [
                 {
                     "ServerName":  "server.name",
                     "Installed":  204,
                     "Downloaded":  60,
                     "Failed":  0,
                     "PendingReboot":  0,
                     "NotInstalled":  112,
                     "Needed":  172,
                     "LastUpdated":  "sexta-feira, 23 de outubro de 2020 06:09:09"
                 },
```

O ideal seria ficar neste formato:

```js
{
    "data":  [
                 {
                     "ServerName":  "server.name",
...                                 ^           ^
...
                     "LastUpdated":  "sexta-feira, 23 de outubro de 2020 06:09:09"
                 },                  ^                                           ^
```

Tentei `/\b(\")+(?!:)/g` mas não funciona para mim pois só dá *match* nas últimas aspas:

```js
 "data":  [
      ^            {
                     "ServerName":  "server.name",
...                                             ^
...
                    "LastUpdated":  "sexta-feira, 23 de outubro de 2020 06:09:09"
                                                                                ^
```

Como eu poderia fazer?

Comment: Qual linguagem você está utilizando? Tem algum motivo de estar usando regex ao invés de usar algum parser de json?

Comment: Na verdade estou usando script em Powershell,. Tenho que retirar essas aspas e só consegui pensar no -replace com Regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa regex pega somente a aspas após os dois pontos:

```
:\s+(\")
```

Teste: https://regex101.com/r/a3vTyR/2

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta :)
Porém, eu precisaria mesmo pegar apenas as aspas após o ":", sem o conteúdo remanescente.

Comment: Alterei a resposta, é só colocar o grupo de match na primeira aspas nesse caso.

Comment: Fiz uma adaptação com a que me passou e funcionou para  o que eu precisava.
Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

## Não use regex, use um *parser* de JSON

Sei que a regex "funcionou" para o seu caso específico, mas nem sempre vai funcionar, pois [regex não é a melhor ferramenta para trabalhar com JSON](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/357086/112052).

Se você usar o que foi [proposto pela outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/479463/112052) (`:\s+(\")`) funciona para o seu caso específico, mas basta que o JSON tenha algo assim:

```js
{ "data": [ { "abc":  "xyz: " } ] }
```

Que a regex também pegará a última aspas (já que ela está depois de um `:` seguido de um ou mais espaços), [veja](https://regex101.com/r/NZKs41/1).

> "*Ah, mas no meu caso não tem isso*"

Tudo bem, mas a ideia do Stack Overflow é que as respostas sejam úteis não só para quem perguntou, mas para qualquer visitante futuro, então acho interessante acrescentar ao assunto, explicando porque nem sempre regex será uma boa opção.

---

Isso acontece porque regex trabalha com texto de forma "genérica", sem considerar o contexto nem analisar a estrutura do mesmo. Por isso podem ocorrer inúmeros problemas ao tentar analisar um texto estruturado, como é o caso de JSON e [HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) (só para ficar em 2 exemplos).

Claro que você poderia incrementar cada vez mais a regex para considerar estes casos. Por exemplo, se mudar para:

```regex
\"[^\"]+\"\s*:\s*(\")
```

Aí eu considero que antes dos dois-pontos tem que ter algum conteúdo entre aspas (`\"` indica as aspas, e `[^\"]+` é "[um ou mais caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) que [**não** sejam](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) aspas"). Também troquei `\s+` (um ou mais espaços) por `\s*` (zero ou mais espaços), já que `"abc" : "xyz: "` e `"abc":"xyz: "` são ambos válidos. Isso resolve o caso acima, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/NZKs41/2). Mas será que resolve todos?

---

E se o JSON tiver aspas escapadas com `\` dentro de alguma string? Por exemplo:

```js
{ "data": [ "abc \"texto entre aspas\" : " ] }
```

A regex vai considerar que `"texto entre aspas\"` é um texto entre aspas (ou seja, vai dar *match* no trecho `\"[^\"]+\"` da expressão), depois tem um espaço, dois-pontos, espaço e `"`, então a regex vai encontrar as aspas de fechamento (e repare que esta string está em um array, nem tem a mesma estrutura que você queria).

Aí começa a ficar cada vez mais complicado para poder tratar todos os casos possíveis. Você teria que adicionar este caso especial (dentro de aspas pode ter também `\"`), e veja como vai ficando cada vez mais complicado. No pior caso, você pode acabar tendo que escrever [um *parser* completo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3845829), o que sinceramente não vale a pena.

É mais fácil usar um *parser* específico (a maioria das linguagens de programação possui algum, seja nativo ou em bibliotecas externas), analisar os tipos de dados que você quer ("se forem strings que são valores de um objeto eu faço X", por exemplo), mudá-los e manipulá-los de acordo com o que você precisa e salvar o JSON modificado. É bem melhor e menos propenso a erros do que usar regex (e [nem é tão complicado assim](https://hkotsubo.github.io/blog/2019-04-13/como-ler-e-manipular-um-json)).

Apesar de ser "legal" - eu particularmente gosto bastante - e até "funcionar" em alguns casos, [regex nem sempre é a melhor solução](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).